# AWS S3 - UserKeyMustBeSpecified error when deleting multiple objects

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have been experiencing UserKeyMustBeSpecified errors lately when deleting multiple objects from s3, using keys without version.

The operation is performed in a Java lambda function, which uses the following code:

```
public class S3Dao {

    private final AmazonS3 s3;
    private Logger logger;

    public S3Dao() {
        BasicAWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
        ClientConfiguration config = new ClientConfiguration();
        config.setConnectionTimeout(220_000);
        config.setClientExecutionTimeout(220_000);
        this.s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withClientConfiguration(config)
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds))
                .build();
    }

    public void deleteKeys(Collection<String> s3keysToDelete) {
        logger.log("Deleting S3 " + s3keysToDelete.size() + " keys");
        if (s3keysToDelete.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        DeleteObjectsRequest deleteRequest = new DeleteObjectsRequest(bucketName)
                .withKeys(s3keysToDelete.toArray(new String[] {}));
        DeleteObjectsResult deleteObjectsResult = s3.deleteObjects(deleteRequest);
        logger.log("Deleted " + deleteObjectsResult.getDeletedObjects().size() + " s3 objects");
    }
}
```

I double checked the access keys, but they're fine.

Does anyone know what this "user key" is, and how I can specify it?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this answer is helpfull https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31010231/com-amazonaws-services-s3-model-amazons3exception-user-key-must-be-specified

Comment: Yes I saw that answer, but unfortunately it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the keys I was trying to delete was `null`. Problem solved :)